# How to get interactive charts and audio from .ipynb in VSCode on macOS

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

My `.ipynb` notebook contains:

```
from IPython.display import display, Audio
display( Audio( myNumpyArray, rate=48000 ) )
```

Working from a web-browser .ipynb editor (Jupyter?) this would create an object in the cell output that I could click to play the audio.

In VSCode I get the object:
[image]

However it is unresponsive to click.

Another example, I'm trying to print x/y coords on a matplotlib plot as I move the mouse  over them.

```
    # TEST: https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor
    %matplotlib notebook

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from mpldatacursor import datacursor

    data = np.outer(range(10), range(1, 5))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    lines = ax.plot(data)
    ax.set_title('Click somewhere on a line')

    datacursor(lines)

    plt.show()
```

This works from browser (Jupyter?), but no output from VSCode.
If I remove the `%matplotlib notebook` I get the plot, but no interactivity.

I'm on macOS.  I would love to use VSCode's .ipynb functionality, but I really need these 'interactive' outputs.

Is it possible?

Most grateful if anyone can help me understand the situation. Presumably it's to do with supported/unsupported "notebook backends".

Comment: use `%matplotlib`, or choose a different Matplotlib backend

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely this will be fixed. It's by design.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1012